# C# How do I preserve a newline through a databind?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a textbox (multi-line) on a WinForm that accepts enter. It is databound to an object that I've created. When I type :

```
"hello
world"
```

I see that the value in my object is "hello\r\nworld", as expected. But when I leave the object and re-bind to it again later, the text field has "helloworld" all bunched up. When I look at the field again, it is "hello\nworld". The \r was stripped out some how.

Where does the \r go during the databinding process?? What can I do to ensure it stays?

Comment: AHA! I found it... when I serialize it out, and bring it back (thus how I was "rebinding"... I would save the file and re-open it) the newlines were screwed up. I have done serialization a million times, so I just assumed it was in the binding. I've proven it is in the serialization piece!

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` means the HEX code `0xD 0xA` and that (Only in Windows) means a new line directive, I think, when you data-bind the text content `\r\n` gets converted to its generic one `\n`, that's why you get it as `helloworld` as a shown text, and `hello\rworld` as data, but it won't be handled as a new line since it is only provided with the `\r Carriage Return` directive and not with the `\n Line Feed` directive.

I think you can use

```
Environment.NewLine
```

to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
("hello\r\nplagiarism world").Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

?

**edited**

Comment: Are you replacing the string `hello\r\nplagiarism world` by `Environment.NewLine`?